# Trigger audio play with jQuery in HTML slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, audio

I'm using bootstrap's carousel template, and have a short audio file associated with each slide. I was wondering how to trigger each audio file as the user switches to the corresponding slide, and also pauses the current file when the slide is switched (and then plays that slide's file.)

Something like this series of events:

- Display slide 1, trigger audio 1
- Display slide 2, pause audio 1, trigger audio 2

and so on. I'm very new to jquery/javascript, so all the help you can give is appreciated!

Here's my HTML carousel code:

```
<div class="mycarousel">
 <div class="carousel-item active">
   <img src="img1.jpg">
     <div class="container">
      *slide 1 contents
      </div>
     <audio src="audio1.mp3"></audio>
 </div>
 <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="img1.jpg">
      <div class="container">
       *slide 2 contents*
      </div>
   <audio src="audio2.mp3"></audio>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use the events that Bootstrap carousel raises to play/pause the relevant `audio` element: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events

Comment: Instead of having multiple audio tag, Have only one and use below,
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  // change audio tag src as you wish
})

Comment: Are able to trigger the click
$("audio").trigger('click');

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I assume that would mean something like $("audio").on('slide.bs.carousel')? If I use "function() {" after that, am I then supposed to link each audio file subsequently?

Comment: If you could show a working example of your code in a snippet or jsFiddle I can give you a more concrete example

Comment: Finicky to get working in a fiddle, but here's a somewhat working slideshow? https://jsfiddle.net/4mhejg32/2/

Essentially I want to trigger each corresponding audio clip as each slide is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this :

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel().on('slid.bs.carousel', function (evt) {
    // find the currently displayed DOM element's audio
    var $thisAudio = $(evt.relatedTarget).find('audio');
    // find all other audio elements and pause them
    $(evt.target).find('audio').not($thisAudio).each(function(i, audio) {
        audio.pause();
    });
    // play this audio
    $thisAudio.get(0).play();
}).carousel(0); // should trigger the first slide's audio?
```

*May well need debugging*

There are still decisions to make, in particular :

- whether the carousel should be initilized only after all the audios are ready to play (slightly involved).
- whether the audios should loop or not - `<audio src="..." loop="true"></audio>` or `<audio src="..." loop="false"></audio>`.
- whether the user should be given the option to silence the audio.